# Need to display 2 input text after selecting a specific value in drop down in angular 4

Tags: angular, dropdown, inputbox

I have a specific requirement. I need to display 2 input text fields after selecting a specific value from a drop down which is 'Add New...'
My code snippet is below -

```
    <td>
    <div *ngIf="item.showOperationField">
        <p-checkbox
            value ="inflationaryImpactCheck"
            label="Save for Inflationary Impact"
            name = "calculationSaveInflation"
            [(ngModel)]="item.inflationaryImpact"
            pTooltip="Check the Inflationary Impact box to map this calculation to an index for Inflationary Pressure calculation."
            binary="true">
        </p-checkbox>
    </div>
    </td>
    <td>
    <div *ngIf="item.inflationaryImpact">
        <p-dropdown
            [style]="{'width':'200px'}"
            [options]="inflation"
            name = "calculationInflation"
            [(ngModel)]="item.selectedInflation">
        </p-dropdown>
    </div>
    </td>
<td>
<div *ngIf="item.selectedInflation=='Add New...'">
   <input
    [style]="{'width':'200px'}"
    type="text"
    name="catValue"
    pInputText
    [(ngModel)]="item.catValue"
    />
</div>
</td>
```

Now I need to display 2 input boxes while selecting a specific value from the drop down "inflation" which is 'Add New...'. I have tried with the above  code snippet but nothing happened.
Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the `ngIf` condition

```
<td>
<div *ngIf="item.inflationaryImpact">
    <p-dropdown
        [style]="{'width':'200px'}"
        [options]="inflation"
        name = "calculationInflation"
        [(ngModel)]="item.selectedInflation">
    </p-dropdown>
</div>
</td>
<td *ngIf="item.selectedInflation === 'Add New...'">
<div>
    <input type="text" name="txt 1"/>
    <input type="text" name="txt 2"/>
</div>
</td>
```

Comment: Sanchila, I have edited my post. Please see. I forgogt add a particular code snippet which I modified now. Somehow it seems so simple but not wokking..

Comment: can you create a plnkr

Answer (score 0):

Hope you have not changed the change detection, and left it as default.
If change detection is On-push, then trigger change detection manually.

Comment: I did not get you

Comment: `@Component({
    selector: '**',
    templateUrl: './**.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./**.component.css'],
    changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})`

Have you changed ur changed detection strategy like this or the default one?

Comment: or if ngIf is not working , try [class.hidden]="!(item.selectedInflation === 'Add New...')"

Answer (score 0):

You should use a FormGroup or FormArray(better way but for your code maybe FormGroup is better) in the component class and when 'Add new' is selected trigger a funtion that add a new FormControl to the FormGroup or FormArray, then use *ngFor in the html template.

```
<div *ngIf="item.selectedInflation==='Add New...'">
<div [formGroupName]="FormGroup" *ngFor="let entry of FormGroup.controls; let i=index" >
   <input
    [style]="{'width':'200px'}"
    type="text"
    name="catValue"
    pInputText
    [(ngModel)]="item.catValue"
    />
</div>
</div>
</td>
```

This work for adding a new input everythime 'Add new' is selected, but if you want to show only one input then the *ngIf should work, if not check [(ngModel)] maybe the problem is there or maybe the string in item.selectedInflation is not equal to 'Add New...'. Anyway post more code for a better answer.

```
 <div *ngIf="item.selectedInflation==='Add New...'">
```